# How to merge 2 yaml files with variables dependencies?

Tags: javascript, yaml

Minimal case  :
File1

```
default : 'my variable to inject'
```

File 2 :

```
password : ${default}
```

Expected Output :

```
default : 'my variable to inject'
password : 'my variable to inject'
```

Expected input code :

```
console.log(mergeYamlFile('f1.yaml', 'f2.yaml'))
```

Comment: `${default}` is nothing special in YAML and gets parsed as string. Are you already using some templating engine to replace such scalars in the same file or are you asking for both how to merge two YAML files and how to interpret such scalars as references?

Comment: Yes ${default} is nothing. I want to use a tool who inpect both file and replace specific variable with a value contain in another file.

Comment: But you *also* want to merge File1 and File2 according to your expected output. That leaves some questions, like should replacement also work if the target is already in the same file.